# Writing and downloading files clientside crossbrowser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html5-filesystem

I have a program where the user does some actions (i.e. clicking on several buttons). I want to record their clicks and the buttons that they click to allow the user to then download a text file with a record of their clicks when they click a separate "download" button. I looked at the File-system APIs for HTML 5, but they seemed to not have cross-browser support. I would ideally like to have this entire file generation and download scheme be entirely client-side, but I am open to server-side ideas as well.

TL;DR: Essentially I'm looking for an equivalent to Java's FileWriter, FileReader, ObjectOutputStream, and ObjectInputStream within Vanilla JS or jQuery (would like to stay away from php, but I'll use it as a last option).

Also, why don't all browsers support the filesystem api? (I'm guessing that it would make MSWord and Pages go out of business with all the open source clientside text editors that could come out.)

Comment: Recording a click would require writing to a file or a database. I'd opt for the latter. Using a DB wouldn't rely on cross-browser dependancy.

Comment: I'd really like to use the writing to a file method. I don't have access to a db as my webserver is kind of limited in scope and I'm looking to run this webpage mainly through clientside

Comment: Also, if my users are mainly using chrome or chrome os, would there be a way to do this client-side specifically for their browser? I could always redirect from a common page based on their browser to different version of the page

Comment: You can look into using a flatfile database. Google that term, you will find many results. This is one of those results http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdb-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the HTML5-File-system is [no longer a part of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/), long story short FF refused to implement because they claimed everything you could do in the File-System API was doable in the HTML5 Indexeddb (which was mostly true). Please see [this blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/why-no-filesystem-api-in-firefox/) for more on why FF didn't implement. I do not know IE's story. (I may have exagerated why FireFox didn't implement, I'm still bummed because you cannot actually do everything in indexeddb that you can do in the noew "Chrome File-system API")

Typically if two of those three browsers implement a spec, it stays in the spec. Otherwise that spec gets orphaned. However, I'm fairly certain a large reason the file-system api didn't take off is because of the IndexedDB API ([caniuse IndexedDB](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb)) really took off when both specs were introduced. If you want cross browser support, check this api out.

That all said if you are still set on the file-system api some developers wrote a [nice wrapper around the IndexedDB](https://github.com/ebidel/idb.filesystem.js), the File-system api wouldn't actually supply you with a stream anyway. You would have to keep appending events to a given file given a fileWriter object. you'd then have to read the entire file  and send to the server via an ajax request and then downloaded from the server once successfully uploaded.

The better route would be to use the IndexedDB apiwhich as stated on [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)

> 1. Open a database.
> 2. Create an object store in upgrading database.
> 3. Start a transaction and make a request to do some database operation, like adding or retrieving data.
> 4. Wait for the operation to complete by listening to the right kind of DOM event.
> 5. Do something
>      with the results (which can be found on the request object).

Here are a couple tutorials on the IndexedDB.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/

As for giving the user that file, as mentioned briefly before you would have to upload the file to the server and download upon the "download" request. Unfortunately you have to trick the user into giving them the data already on their machine. Anyway, hope this all helps.